# PowerShell Script To check Files in a folder

Tags: powershell, file, directory

need your help iam kind of stuck i need to create a powershell script that take id number from csv file and then check in a specific folder (and all sub folders) for all files with that id number exists in the name of the file and then move all the files to a folder that i choose

Thank in advence

Comment: SO is not a scripting service. Please provide some code you wrote and describe the error you encountered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61922785/edit) your question and show us the first three or four lines of the CSV file you use as input. Also show us some examples of the file names that shoud apply.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you.

```
$fileNames = gc Your\csv\path\MyCSVFile.csv

    foreach($file in $fileNames)
    {
        Get-ChildItem -Path your\source\folder\path\SourceFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $file} |  Move-Item -Destination your\dest\folder\path\DestinationFolder
    }
```